# How to extend Rails models?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, design-patterns, refactoring

Say, I have a Rails model with a method:

```
class Order < ApplicationRecord
  def process
    do_some
    do_some_more
    do_even_more_here
  end
end
```

Its purpose is solely Rails-model based, meaning its actions are performed on the object itself. What would be the best design pattern to adapt if I'd want to refactor this method and move it out somewhere else?

What I've found so far is that a `Decorator` shouldn't be the answer as they are more `view` related. `ServiceObject` is meant to only perform calculations without the ActiveRecord object and `Concerns` are `mixins` that divide responsibilities over several (ActiveRecord) objects.

Comment: This sounds like a service object to me. I've not heard of the distinction "only perform calculations without the ActiveRecord object." Can you elaborate why that constraint is important?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> What I've found so far is that a Decorator shouldn't be the answer as
>   they are more view related.

Yes, the decorator pattern is most often used in Rails apps to decorate models with view specific behavior. That does not necessarily mean that you can't use the pattern for other purposes.

Rather what you should consider is that models even with no code instead are already fat objects due to the insane amount of features that they get from ActiveModel and ActiveRecord:

- validations
- persistence
- dirty tracking
- type casting
- querying
- etc

A decorator may just add more fat even through the code is neatly tucked away in a separate class.

> ServiceObject is meant to only perform calculations without the
>   ActiveRecord object

Stop listening to whoever told you this. The ServiceObject pattern is really just about creating single purpose objects that do one single job and do it well.

ActiveJob is an example of the ServiceObject pattern. And yes it even has an API for passing in ActiveRecord objects. What you are describing sound like a prime candidate for a ServiceObject or ActiveJob.

> Concerns are mixins that divide responsibilities over several
>   (ActiveRecord) objects.

Mixins don't divide responsibilities. They share behaviors between classes. Its basically like copy-pasting the same methods between a set of classes.

Answer (score 0):

Service object is the one you are looking for. 
Mixins and concerns are just a bunches of code you want to mix and share, they can be anywhere. 
Make a service object, design it’s public and private interfaces. If you are thinking it’s coming too fat just separate them, easy as that. It might worth reading about SOLID.